# SQL data not displaying properly when selecting multiple columns

Tags: mysql, cygwin, mariadb

When I run the following code, I get garbled output

```
MariaDB> select c.customer_id,c.name,o.order_name 
from customers c 
left join orders o on c.customer_id = o.customer_id;
```

When I just select a single column, the data looks ok

```
MariaDB> select c.customer_id 
from customers c 
left join orders o on c.customer_id = o.customer_id;
```

I am running Cygwin64 and MariaDB database.

[image: screen shot of output]

Edit: Here are some screen shots when just querying customers.name and orders.order_name.

[More screen shots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWiKL.png)

It is not the font. The font is fixed space.

[Font is fixed space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlKNK.png)

Comment: Does single column output is safe when `c.name` or `o.order_name` instead of `c.customer_id` is selected?

Comment: The output is garbled when I type "select name from customers" and "select order_name from orders".

Comment: This means these fields contains symbols which cannot be displayed in terminal correctly... maybe it is possible to find a font which will show these symbols, maybe not (and check if terminal cannot display multi-byte symbols at all).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing garbled about the output. The terminal is not using fixed size fonts so the output is proportionally spaced which is why it looks the way it does.

Comment: The font on the screenshot looks like fixed, not proprotional.

Comment: You're right, it could be a fixed font.